# Join method is waiting when it shouldn't be waiting

Tags: java, multithreading

Below is my code. In the class called Threads, I am not understanding how the t1.join() is working. It is supposed to wait there until that thread is finished. So the first time the run method runs it should start the new thread, then the current thread should have nothing to wait on and it should just go down and print its name. But all the threads are waiting until the last thread is finished and then the threads terminate in reverse order. This is what the program is supposed to do, but I do not understand how it is working. I hope my question is described good enough.

Main Class

```
public class Project 
{


public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException 
{
    Threads t1 = new Threads(1);
    t1.setName("Thread 1");
    t1.start();
    t1.join();
   System.out.println("First Thread Finished");




    //Thread.sleep(5000);
    //System.out.println(Threads.que.get(5).isAlive());
}

}
```

Threads Class

```
public class Threads extends Thread
{

private int i;

public Threads(int i) 
{        
    this.i = i;
}

@Override
public void run()
{

    i++;
    if(i <= 6)
    {
        Threads t = new Threads(i);
        t.setName("Thread " + i);
        t.start();  
        try {
            t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

        }
        System.out.println(getName());
    }


}

}
```

Comment: Do you realize that you are creating a new thread only after the previous thread is done.

Comment: No, previous thread doesn't finish until new thread is finished. This is the program output. Thread 5
Thread 4
Thread 3
Thread 2
Thread 1
First Thread Finished
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: You are right it is `if`not `while`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what is happening (behaves like recursion call):

1) Main Thread creates `Thread1` and waits for it to finish.

2) `Thread1` creates `Thread2` and waits for it to finish.

3) `Thread2` creates `Thread3` and waits for it to finish.

4) `Thread3` creates `Thread4` and waits for it to finish.

5) `Thread4` creates `Thread5` and waits for it to finish.

6) `Thread5` creates `Thread6` and waits for it to finish.

7) `Thread6` does not print anything and finishes (since it does not enter `if` statement).

8) Then `Thread5` comes out of `join` call,  prints "Thread5" and finishes.

9) Then `Thread4` comes out of `join` call,  prints "Thread4" and finishes.

10) Then `Thread3` comes out of `join` call, prints "Thread3" and finishes.

11) Then `Thread2` comes out of `join` call, prints "Thread2" and finishes.

12) Then `Thread1` comes out of `join` call, prints "Thread1" and finishes.

13) Finally main thread comes out of `join` call and prints "First Thread Finished".

Comment: Thank you. Just looking at you posting the basic logic helped me solve my question.

Comment: Hey do you know why I got -4 votes on this question? Did I format wrong or something? I thought it was a good, fun question.

Comment: I believe it was a good question. I noticed folks here are a little "downvote happy", especial with questions from low rating users. Another reason is that you could probably find out answer yourself with some debugging.